# How do I get doxygen to list all namespace members on the namespace documentation page?

Tags: c++, namespaces, doxygen, documentation-generation

In a C++ project of mine, have a bunch of functions in some namespace; and both the functions and the namespace have doxygen comments. I can see the function documentation through the doxygen page generated for the files they're in; but on the namespace's page, I see nothing other than the namespace's doxygen comment; nothing about its contents.

How can I get doxygen to have the namespace page also have the documentation of all of that namespace's functions (and type definitions, constants etc?)

Notes:

- My documentation was generated by Doxygen 1.8.12
- I don't care if sub-namespaces are included or just linked-to.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? The namespace page only gives an overview of the namespaces and the classes in the namespaces. I assume you are talking about functions in the namespace that are not in a class. Maybe you can give an example and maybe it is worth an enhancement  request.

Comment: @albert: 1.8.12, as used [here](https://codedocs.xyz/eyalroz/cuda-kat/). Indeed, not functions in a class - freestanding functions in a namespace. The repository is my [cuda-kat](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-kat).

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.12 is very old, please update to the current version (1.9.4). A repository is most of the time a moving target and not really a (minimal) example.

Comment: @albert: I would love to, but it's not my website. I'll ask the codedocs people to update. Maybe you could contact them as well?

Comment: Project looks like to be a bit dead regarding code update. I left a message with the issue https://github.com/CodeDocs/CodeDocs/issues/26 I don't know another  way to contact them